# how to update navbar in header in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue with my navbar updating...After login with my credentials my navbar is not updating..however my response is success..but how to update change my header..it have to show logout after login..Her is my Html code.How to write authentication for this..Please help me out.I am at end of my project..

```
<div ng-controller="NavbarCtrl" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" id="header">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/"><i class="ion-ios7-pulse-strong">Onio</i><img src="images/onio1.png"/></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul ng-if="isAuthenticated()" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#/products">Products</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul ng-if="!isAuthenticated()" class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
            <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul ng-if="!isAuthenticated()" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/signup">Sign up</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul ng-if="isAuthenticated()" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#/logout">Logout</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="navbar-avatar dropdown-toggle">Welcome, {{userInfo}}
            </a></li>
        </ul>

        <!--<ul ng-if="!isAuthenticated()" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">-->
        <!--&lt;!&ndash;<li><button class="btn btn-facebook" ng-click="fbLogoutUser()">FBLogOut</button></li>&ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--<li class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" ng-click="FBLogin()" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false"> </li>-->
        <!--</ul>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, you need to make sure that isAuthenticated() returns a truthy value if the user is authenticated, and a falsy value if it's not. But you didn't post your code so...

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I was asked the same how to to write general authentication for header.Please help me

Comment: can u provide a sample example for this